# How to save a graph drawn with the drawing tool?

Tags: front-end, drawing

How do I save a graph that has been drawn with the drawing tool? As you can see from my screenshot, all the save buttons are disabled.

[image: Hand drawn graphH]

Comment: Select all elements of your graphics with mouse, then right-click on it and choose "Group". Select the graphics again with left-click and choose from menu "File"->"Save Selection As..." . This worked for me. But I recommend that you create your graphics programmatically instead.

Comment: Can you give me an example how to create a graph programmatically?

Comment: This draws 5 random ellipses and exports the graphics. `r := RandomReal[];` `ellipse := Circle[{r, r}, {r, r}];` `gr = Graphics[Table[{RandomColor[], ellipse}, {5}]];`  
`Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "elipses.png"}], gr];` 
`gr`

Comment: @Pinti There are many things which are easier to draw with the drawing tool rather than using code, I assume OP's scenario is one of those scenarios.

Comment: @Pinti I do not want 5 random elipses.  I belive this code does not work for me. What I mean that is not what I want

Answer (score 2):

You have to right click on the bracket to the right of the figure and then choose "Save Selection As".

[image]

Alternatively you can copy the figure with ctrl+c on Windows or cmd+c on MacOS, or with the copy button in the "Edit" menu, and then paste it (with ctrl+v, cmd+v or via the edit menu) into a code cell where you can export it with the `Export` function.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  In order to save the graph, you have to draw the graph in the area that is generated by code like {Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> 800]}

Comment: @bios Yes, I assumed that is what you had done. I included it in my screenshot for clarity.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer!